# Pg_dijkstra empty results

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, topology, pgadmin-3

I am currently working on PgAdmin, and the pgrouting extension, in order to get the length and the path of the shortest path between every LNG terminal over the world (I have them as a table of points).
Thus I created a wolrdwild grid, that avoid lands as the boats carrying the LNG has to go only through the sea.
I have the LNG terminals as a table of points.
I linked every terminal (point) to the grid with st_shortestline, so I got a table shortestline.
Then I got the completed network by merging the shortesline table and the grid table. So this network links every LNG terminal over the world.

This network being created, I processed the topology as :

```
ALTER TABLE network
ADD COLUMN source integer,
ADD COLUMN target integer,
ADD COLUMN cost double precision,
ADD COLUMN x1 double precision,
ADD COLUMN y1 double precision,
ADD COLUMN x2 double precision,
ADD COLUMN y2 double precision;

UPDATE network
SET x1=st_x(st_startpoint(geom)),
y1=st_y(st_startpoint(geom)),
x2=st_x(st_endpoint(geom)),
y2=st_y(st_endpoint(geom));

CREATE INDEX network_idx ON network USING gist (geom);

SELECT pgr_createTopology('network', 0.000000001, 'geom', 'id');
```

Then I got the "network_vertices_pgr" table.
I wanted to process the pgr_dijkstra algorithm from one terminal to another, and for every terminal. It would give me the shortest path between every pair of LNG terminal.
So I created a mediator table called "table_correspondance" telling me, for every LNG terminal point, to which id from the network_vertices_pgr table it corresponds with.
Then I processed pgr_dijkstra with the id of one terminal as Source (id known with the table_correspondance) and the id of another terminal Target (also known with the table_correspondance).

Unfortunately, I realised the algorithm was working only for somme source/target couple. Several couple of terminal points (about 75% of them) just give void results, and I can't figure out why.
For instance, the following instruction give a void result :

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost
FROM pgr_Dijkstra('SELECT id, source, target, cost, x1, y1, x2, y2 FROM network', 20, 50, FALSE, FALSE);
```

I used pgr_kdijkstra to see on QGIS the Source/Target couples whose the paths were accurately processed. First I thought it was because of the grid that had isolated lines leading to deadends, that could give void results.
But I noticed on QGIS that, for the same source with pgr_kdijkstra, some targets were processed whereas other target, very close geographically, were not processed. And the grid around them was continuous.
When I run the pgr_analyseGraph, it returns OK, there is,apparently, no problem with the network.

I realised the global code many times, but I always get this problem.
I also checked my "table_correspondance" (representing every LNG terminal point), and it's accurate : each point matches with a point in the "network_vertices_pgr" table (representing every point of the network).

If it's not a problem with the network structure nor a problem with source/target points, I really can't figure out why it's not working.

The only thing that could be a problem, but I couldn't really understand why if it was :
When I create the topology with the network table and pgr_createTopology, some lines have empty "source" and "target" values.
But pg_dijkstra requires to get ride of the lines having null values in the Source column to process. So I deleted them.

Would you have any idea why it would keep not working for me?

Comment: I think the empty source and target are likely to be a clue. Have you tried loading this with osm2pgrouting to compare results?

Comment: I don't know about osm2pgrouting yet, I will take a look about it, thanks.
Indeed I think that's a clue, but I tried to load the network table into qgis and when I try to look at the features having empty source and target, it doesn't appear. So those features have no geometry.
That's strange, because my table network was originally created with geometry features. It means that, when I create the topology, it create features in the network table on its own....and that's odd as well because it should just fill the source/tgarget column and create the network_vertice table.

Comment: When I run the pg_kDijkstra from one source to multiple target, I get a lot fo empty results. For example I took a screen shot of a part of the result as seen on QGIS. We can clearly see that some points have accurate results but other points, accurately connected to the grid, are not treated by the algorithm. 
The "table_correspondance" contains all the nodes of the network I am interested in running Dijkstra algorithm as Source/Target.
http://hpics.li/7e23bae